# is there a way to make __init__.py behave exactly the same as another file in python?

Tags: python, package

I was working with a package in python that i realized if i import the package and change a variable in it, the variable will remain unchanged when i try to access it in the package later.
i tested on a simple example with just three files like this:

test/
|-test.py
|-lib/
..|-lib.py
..|-__init__.py

and i imported the contents of lib in __init__ like this

```py
# __init__.py
from .lib import *
```

contents of lib.py and test.py where as seen bellow:

```py
# lib.py
a = 10
def foo():
    print(a)
```

```py
# test.py
import lib
lib.a = 20
lib.foo()
# prints 10
```

running test.py will print 10 which is the initial value of a.
but if i import lib in test.py like this `import lib.lib` , it would print 20.
so i was wondering if there is a way to make __init__ behave exactly the same as lib.py?

EDIT:
I used variable holders (if I'm not wrong) which means I created some classes (with no init mehod) which just held the variables I wanted to change and I didn't have to move the content of lib.py to __init__.py.
but for future usage, doing that is the best choice at this point.

Comment: probably leave the file `__init__.py` empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's what you want, then just put what's in `lib.py` into `__init__.py` (and get rid of `lib.py`).

```
#__init__.py
a = 10
def foo():
    print(a)
```

```
>>> import lib
>>> lib.a = 20
>>> lib.foo()
20
```

Answer (score 0):

`lib.a = 10` is just creating a variable `a` in `lib`.

Instead, you meant to set the variable `lib.lib.a = 20`, like this:

```
import lib
lib.lib.a = 20
lib.foo()
# prints 20
```

Comment: well that works well. However I was looking for a way to change the **\_\_init\_\_.py** file to behave like lib.py.